# Is there a way to live update app while writing angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, ide, livereload

I want to create an angularjs app but each time it requires to press the refresh button in the browser to get the update. thus it bring to this question:

**Is there any way to get live update while writing angularjs app?** So I don't need to press the refresh button each time I make changes in my angularjs app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use **[grunt](http://gruntjs.com/)** which is a task runner written in node, grunt has a plugin called **[grunt-contrib-livereload](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-livereload)** that reloads the page whenever there are changes in the files/directories that you want to watch. Alternatively, there's a scaffolding tool for client side web applications in AngularJS called **[yeoman](http://yeoman.io/)**, that has a generator called **[generator-angular](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular)** - this generator has an opinionated structure towards AngularJS application development and it comes with a basic setup that you can use for livereloading code changes from any files that you have configured to watch.

Answer (score 1):

Start using yeoman. It has grunt that will solve yr problem plus lots of more exciting stuff.
Check this quick start guide : http://yeoman.io/learning/

Answer (score 0):

I use the open source editor **Brackets.io** by Adobe. Just click the lightning icon button to the right of the editor to run your web page and will auto refresh for every save.

Comment: 1. I start a simple node server so that Adobe Brackets has something to latch on to. 
2. Set that url as the host for the app serving index.html. 
3. Click the lightning bolt. [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dj59p5LFpvc)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in many ways. Many of the options are already mentioned in this post. All of them are workable. In my experience the most simplistic way to do this by the following way.No configuration , No setting , No need to code anything.
Just add this line in your `<head> </head>` tag of the html file

```
<script src="http://livejs.com/live.js"></script>
```